# Create extension till model plan and not till layout in Autocad

Tags: plugins, autocad, cad

I am using Autocad 2012, there is model and layout.

I want to create extension till model plan only but not till layout plan.

Any idea how to do that?

Also any link where I can get drawhatch11.vlx file? I need to create my own hatch file.